# How to use a select pivot query to update two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to update data in two different table however based on select query using pivot I'm unsure how to go about to do the update query.

See query I have below

```
update [FuelManagementSystem].[dbo].[OpenCloseTank] set OpenDip=0.00 , CloseDip=0.00 where WhenDate =getDate() and TankID='BW-TK-DSL1'
update [FuelManagementSystem].[dbo].[OpenCloseNozzle] set OpenReading=0.00, CloseReading=0.00 where Date =getDate() and TankID='BW-TK-DSL1' and NozzleNo=1
update [FuelManagementSystem].[dbo].[OpenCloseNozzle] set OpenReading=0.00, CloseReading=0.00 where Date =getDate() and TankID='BW-TK-DSL1' and NozzleNo=2
SELECT QUERY

SELECT [Date],T.TankID,[OpenDip],[CloseDip],[ORNozzle1], [CRNozzle1], [ORNozzle2], [CRNozzle2]
       FROM [FuelManagementSystem].[dbo].[OpenCloseTank]T
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT [TankID], [Date], SUM([1]) AS [ORNozzle1], SUM([2]) AS [ORNozzle2]
              FROM [FuelManagementSystem].[dbo].[OpenCloseNozzle] 
                 PIVOT
                 ( MAX (OpenReading)
                           FOR [NozzleNo] IN ([1], [2])
                 ) AS P     
                 WHERE CONVERT(DATE,[Date])='2019-11-09'
                 GROUP BY [TankID], [Date]) AS A  ON [T].[TankID] = [A].[TankID]
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT [TankID], SUM([1]) AS [CRNozzle1], SUM([2]) AS [CRNozzle2]
              FROM [FuelManagementSystem].[dbo].[OpenCloseNozzle] 
                 PIVOT
                 ( MAX (CloseReading)
                           FOR [NozzleNo] IN ([1], [2])
                 ) AS P     
                 WHERE CONVERT(DATE,[Date])='2019-11-09'
                 GROUP BY [TankID]) AS B  ON [T].[TankID] = [B].[TankID]
   where convert(date,Whendate)='2019-11-0'
```

QUERY RESULTS

[image]

TABLE DATA

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. "Update two tables based on pivot select query" just does not make sense to me. (You cannot update two tables with one query, if that is what you are asking)

Comment: Why would you save pivoted data to tables? What are you using to build user interface - Access, vb.net, C#, etc.?

Comment: I’m saving data to pivoted table, I’m just using the select query to display results in c#. Then allow the user to update the tables

Comment: @Alex, guess I worded incorrectly! I’m not using one update query, however I’m unsure of how to update different tables based on how the dat is in the tables. See pictures in the question

Comment: Assuming you want to update base tables based on user changes to pivoted data: not possible with a query, as when aggregating and pivoting you lose row id (PK) associations.

Comment: Oh ok, so there’s no other way it can be done without it being pivoted to allow for the data to be updated? My issue was that the closedip and opendip would repeat in the rows. Unless I use a text box and not a grid view to display the values

Comment: There may be a solution but not in SQL Server. You mentioned C#, is it a Web App or a Windows App? Post another question detailing your front end environment and perhaps someone else may be able to help.

Comment: It’s a web app. But even if so I would still need to use sql query to display and update the tables